# Project won't compile because of Android X

Tags: flutter, androidx

I've cloned a [project](https://github.com/duytq94/flutter-chat-demo) on Github. It uses different plugins.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: 0.1.2
  firebase_auth: 0.7.0
  google_sign_in: 3.2.4
  cloud_firestore: 0.8.2+3
  image_picker: 0.4.12+1
  shared_preferences: 0.4.3
  firebase_storage: 1.0.4
  cached_network_image: 0.7.0
  intl: 0.15.7
```

There is blog [post](https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-a-chat-app-with-flutter-and-firebase-from-scratch-9eaa7f41782e) which advises keeping versions the same. My problem is the image_picker plugin. Looking around stackoverflow it recommends using version `0.4.12+1` if you don't want to migrate app to Android X. Here is my error

```
/Users/gerardhorgan/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/ImagePickerPlugin.java:8: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.VisibleForTesting;
                                 ^
/Users/gerardhorgan/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/ImagePickerDelegate.java:15: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.VisibleForTesting;
                                 ^
/Users/gerardhorgan/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/ImagePickerPlugin.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerPlugin
/Users/gerardhorgan/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/ImagePickerDelegate.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY = 2342;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
/Users/gerardhorgan/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/ImagePickerDelegate.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_IMAGE_WITH_CAMERA = 2343;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
/Users/gerardhorgan/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/ImagePickerDelegate.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_IMAGE_STORAGE_PERMISSION = 2344;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
/Users/gerardhorgan/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/ImagePickerDelegate.java:71: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_IMAGE_PERMISSION = 2345;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
/Users/gerardhorgan/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/ImagePickerDelegate.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_VIDEO_FROM_GALLERY = 2352;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
/Users/gerardhorgan/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/ImagePickerDelegate.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_VIDEO_WITH_CAMERA = 2353;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
/Users/gerardhorgan/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/ImagePickerDelegate.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_VIDEO_STORAGE_PERMISSION = 2354;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
/Users/gerardhorgan/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/ImagePickerDelegate.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_VIDEO_PERMISSION = 2355;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
/Users/gerardhorgan/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/ImagePickerDelegate.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting final String fileProviderName;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
/Users/gerardhorgan/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/ImagePickerDelegate.java:164: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
13 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':image_picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.



BUILD FAILED in 2s
*******************************************************************************************
The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.

*******************************************************************************************
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I'm wondering what might be causing the incompatibilities prevent my app from compiling?

Answer (score 0):

You need to flow the documentation for [AndroidX compatibility](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility)

Comment: I've seen that document. There's a section called Avoiding Android X. Where they give the plugin dependencies versions to pin in your pubspec.yaml. I have pinned with the recommended versions. ie for the image picker: `0.4.12+1`

Answer (score 0):

The best option is migrate the app for androidX. Follow the steps in android-studio:

1) Remove all your dependencies of your pubspec file and run `flutter packages get`

2) Open only android module of your app in android-studio. You can do this with right click on your project root directory > flutter > Open android module in android studio

3) After open only android module in android-studio menu go to Refactor > MigrateToAndoridX...

4) Do the migration!

5) Close android module android-studio instance and go back to your flutter project

6) Insert all your dependencies in pubspec file and run `flutter packages get`

Answer (score 0):

Use `image_picker: ^0.6.6+1` and add AndroidManifest.xml following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

This way worked for me!